# Proof related to monotone functions and induction

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality, induction, monotone-functions

1)$f : N => R$ is monotone increasing $<=> f(n)  $$\leq$$ f(n+1)$ for all $n$ in $N$

2) The function f: R=>R / f(x) = 2x $ - \lfloor\ x \rfloor$ checks that $f(x)$$\leq$$f(x+1)$ however it isn't monotone increasing

Comment: Check your formatting: it is messed up, I think.

Comment: @DonAntonio thanks , I have just edited it

Comment: Well...better (not much, though). The function seems to be $\;f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb R\;,\;\;f(n)=2n-\lfloor n\rfloor\;$ , right? So...what's the question, anyway? To show it is monotone....but not monotone?!? and observe that $\;n\in\Bbb N\implies \lfloor n\rfloor =n\implies f(n)=n\;$ . Perhaps you meant $\;\color{red}{f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb N}\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio my fault , I corrected the mistake . It was R-> R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) If $f$ is monotone increasing obviously $f(n) \leq f(n + 1)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let's prove the other implication. Taken $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n < m$ we have that $m = n + k$ for a $k >0$.

We proceed by induction on $k$. The case $k = 1$ is guaranteed by our hypothesis. We assume the thesis holds for $k$ and we prove it for $k + 1$:
$$f(n + k + 1) \geq f(n + k) \geq f(n)$$
We used the hypothesis for the first inequality and the induction for the second. We proved our proposition.

2) Knowing that $\lfloor x + 1 \rfloor =\lfloor x \rfloor + 1$ we can see that
$$ f(x + 1) = 2x + 2 - \lfloor x + 1 \rfloor = 2x + 1 - \lfloor x \rfloor = f(x) + 1 > f(x) $$
So we proved that for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $f(x) \leq f(x+1)$.

But $f$ is not monotone increasing: $\frac{3}{4} < 1$ but
$$f\left({\frac{3}{4}}\right) = \frac{3}{2} > 1 = f(1)$$.